# Spring Boot App throws ApplicationReadyEvent cannot be cast to WebServerInitializedEvent

Tags: spring-boot

I'm trying to upgrade the Spring boot 1.4.x -> 2.0.0.M3 and am encountering the following error:

Non-matching event type for listener: org.springframework.boot.web.context.ServerPortInfoApplicationContextInitializer

Error:
Java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent can not be cast to org.springframework.boot.web.context.WebServerInitializedEvent

I'm trying to run the application inside Tomcat 8.5, using Java8.

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml? Do you maybe have any version conflicts?

Comment: @dunni I increased the log level of the application and I was able to see a Warning that occurred well before the exception.

  DEBUG 10068 --- [ost-startStop-1] oscore.annotation.AnnotationUtils: Failed to meta-introspect annotation [interface br.com.esig.web.config.WebApplication]: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect. Annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy

The problem was that the EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration class no longer exists and was being used in meta annotation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your error is due to this https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-15838

You can resolve it by updating spring boot 2.0.0.M3 to 2.0.0.M5